# Pass FIRAuthCredential to React Native callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to use Firebase's phone authentication through react native. I've created a native module that with a two methods:

One to verify a user's phone number. This sends the user an SMS with a verification code. This part works fine.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(verifyPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phone callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  [[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider] verifyPhoneNumber:phone
                                          completion:^(NSString * _Nullable verificationID, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
      callback(@[error, [NSNull null]]);
      return;
    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:verificationID forKey:@"authVerificationID"];

    callback(@[[NSNull null], verificationID]);
  }];
}
```

And another to take that code and, with the stored `verificationID`, create a `FIRAuthCredential`. This seems to work as well. If I log the credential in the Native layer I find it is being created and outputs as: `<FIRPhoneAuthCredential: 0x170453950>`

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getCredential:(NSString *)code callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *verificationID = [defaults stringForKey:@"authVerificationID"];

  FIRAuthCredential *credential = [[FIRPhoneAuthProvider provider]
    credentialWithVerificationID:verificationID
                verificationCode:code];

  callback(@[[NSNull null], credential]);
}
```

The trouble I'm having is passing that credential back to the Javascript. I would like to get something that can be used in to sign in.

```
MyNativeModule.getCredential("12345", (error, credential) => {
    ...
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
});
```

But I always just get a `credential` of `null`. How do I go about transforming that credential into something that can be passed in the callback and used in javascript?

Comment: I don't know much about native code but I think [code from react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/ios/RNFirebase/auth/RNFirebaseAuth.m) might help you to get an idea.

Comment: Good idea. But react-native-firebase uses native code to sign the user and doesn't pass the `credential` up to the javascript the way I'm trying to do. I want to eventually move to them, but it seems phone auth is still being implemented and I couldn't get it to work for me. Need this as a interim solution.

Comment: The last time I check the PhoneAuth problem was only on Android side but the implementation of the iOS was easy. Did you check [this comment](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/119#issuecomment-309699767) on the issue?

Comment: Huh. It looks like eneskaya is using the verification code from the native method to create the `credential` in javascript. I'll give that a try. Thanks.